# Enviar a segundo plano con `kill`

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos

¿Cómo puedo enviar un proceso a segundo plano utilizando el comando `kill`?

Lo he probado con varias opciones de la lista pero lo he logrado.

```
 usuario@a2-server01:~$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
```

¿Qué opción debería utilizar?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres enviarlo a background con `kill`? ¿No sería más lógico usar los comandos correspondientes para ello? Hasta donde se, `kill` no permite mandar comandos a segundo plano, solo se utiliza para matar procesos.

Comment: No es sólo para matar procesos, kill -9 mata el proceso porque mandas la señal 9 (SigKill -> Signal kill), pero podrías mandar cualquier otra señal de la lista

Comment: kill sin número manda la señal por defecto, que es SIGTERM (número 15), que *pide* al proceso que termine, pero puede ser ignorada, por eso se usa la señal 9 (SIGKILL) que no puede ser ignorada para matar procesos que no responden (se han *colgado*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente, cuando quieres lanzar un proceso en segundo plano (*background*) desde la línea de comandos, basta con añadir un *et* o *ampersand* (&).

Otra forma de obtener este estado es lanzar el proceso desde la línea de comandos, pulsar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> para pausarlo y luego escribir `bg` para que se siga ejecutando en segundo plano.

Ambas formas trabajan con las siguientes señales:

> - **SIGCONT** - To make processes continue executing after being paused by the SIGTSTP or SIGSTOP signal, send the SIGCONT signal to the paused
>     process. This is the CONTinue SIGnal. This signal is beneficial to
>     Unix job control (executing background tasks).
> - **SIGSTOP** - This signal makes the operating system pause a process's execution. The process cannot ignore the signal.
> - **SIGTSTP** - This signal is like pressing ctrl-z. This makes a request to the terminal containing the process to ask the process to stop
>     temporarily. The process can ignore the request.

[Fuente](https://www.linux.org/threads/kill-commands-and-signals.8881/)

Por tanto, puedes usar SIGTSTP (*Signal Temporary Stop*, señal de pausa temporal) o SIGSTOP (*Signal Stop*, señal de pausa no ignorable) para pausar temporalmente y luego SIGCONT (*Signal Continue*, señal para continuar) para que se siga ejecutando en segundo plano.